# What does it mean denumerable sequence of sets?

Tags: measure-theory

I've been searching for the definition of $\textbf{denumerable sequence of sets}$, but I have not found it yet.

Can someone tell me what doest it mean a denumerable sequence of sets? Thank you!

Comment: denumerable and enumerable are the same thing. i.e. to mean countably infinite or finite.

Comment: And a *denumerable sequence of sets* is a pleonasm, i.e. means the same as just a *sequence of sets*, because every such sequence is obviously denumerable.

Comment: @Adayah That's not necessarily true - in set theory we do sometimes speak of sequences of arbitrary ordinal length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for each $n \in \mathbb N$ a set $M_n$ is given, then you have the sequence

$$(M_1,M_2,M_3,....).$$

Such a sequence is a denumerable sequence of sets.

Comment: Does denumerable mean countable?

Comment: Yes, denumerable means countable.

Answer (score -1):

If you can label each element in the set with a real number, it is denumerable. If a set is denumerable, it is countable. This is a way, in which we may have an infinite countable set

Comment: I think by "real" you mean "natural" ...

Comment: I can label each element of $\mathbb R$ with a real number,  but $\mathbb R$ is not denumerable.